# Java copy array 3d by System.arraycopy()

Tags: java, arrays

How can I copy a 3d array?

```
int[][][] save = new int[9][9][9];

System.arraycopy(p, 0, save, 0, p.length);

for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(p[i], 0, save[i], 0, p[i].length);
    for (int j = 0; j < p[i].length; j++) {
        System.arraycopy(p[i][j], 0, save[i][j], 0, p[i][j].length);
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: it does not work because the first arracopy copies references to the 2d arrays.

Comment: Why don't you check yourself if it works? And if it doesn't, describe what it does, what you expect, what errors did you get etc.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that there is no such thing as a 3D array in Java, since Java only supports one-dimensional arrays. Multi-dimensional arrays are faked by the `new` operator. See Java Language Specification, [Run-Time Evaluation of Array Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1):

> The declaration:
>
> ```
> float[][] matrix = new float[3][3];
> ```
>
> is equivalent in behavior to:
>
> ```
> float[][] matrix = new float[3][];
> for (int d = 0; d < matrix.length; d++)
>     matrix[d] = new float[3];
> ```

The expression `v = matrix[1][2]` actually means `float[] x = matrix[1]; v = x[2]`.

So, when you did `new int[9][9][9]`, Java allocated an array of 9 references, then allocated 9 arrays of 9 references, and finally allocated 81 arrays of 9 values (`int[9]`).

When you then did `System.arraycopy(p, 0, save, 0, p.length)`, you replaced the outer 9 references to point to your source (`p`) subarrays. From there things went really bad.

So, Java has already allocated all the subarrays for you. You just need to copy the 9*9*9=729 `int` values, **but not any of the arrays**.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        System.arraycopy(p[i][j], 0, save[i][j], 0, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `System.arraycopy` is only a shallow copy. Even though the line

```
int[][][] save = new int[9][9][9];
```

creates `new` objects at every level, you immediately transfer references to the nine original arrays `p[0]` - `p[8]` into `save`.

The easiest way to correct this is:

```
int[][][] save = new int[9][9][9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)     // These 2 lines could be replaced by 
            save[i][j][k] = p[i][j][k]; // System.arraycopy as in Andreas's answer
```

If an `int[][][]` is not rectangular, this is more tricky. In that case you'd have to do something like:

```
int[][][] save = new int[p.length][][];
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    save[i] = new int[p[i].length][];
    for (int j = 0; j < p[i].length; j++)
        save[i][j] = Arrays.copyOf(p[i][j], p[i][j].length);
}
```